# Algorithms and Recursion Help?

Tags: algorithm

I have the following recursion: T(n) = 2*T(n/4) + T(n/2) + n and I need to know the exact equation, I know Master theorem won't help me, and the iteration seems to be wrong...

Please tell me how to do it in general for such recursions.
Thanks in advance.

Hey all, thanks for replying I need complexity. I need to understand how to solve such problems.

Comment: Are looking for the algorithm complexity?

Comment: No, I think he is looking for a closed-form solution to the recurrence.

Comment: I guess you want the more general Akra–Bazzi method, instead of the Master Theorem?

Comment: What do you mean by the exact equation please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252985/resource-on-computing-time-complexity-of-algorithms

Comment: @Mencel - that should be an answer, not a comment, so he can mark you correct.

Comment: what do you mean by exact equation? Do you need the closed from? For that you have to know some initial values like T(1), T(0)...

Comment: Also, if this is homework you should tag it as so, so others are not doing your homework for you, but leading you in the right direction :). This looks like a problem from an Advanced Discrete Structures course I took a couple of years back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T(n) = O(nlogn)` and `W(nlogn)`

To prove that, by definition of `O`, we need to find constants `n0` and `c` such that:
for every `n>=n0`, `T(n)<=cnlogn`.

We will use induction on `n` to prove that `T(n)<=cnlogn` for all `n>=n0`

Let's skip the base case for now... (we'll return later)

Hipothesis: We assume that for every `k<n`, `T(k)<=cklogk`

Thesis: We want to prove that `T(n)<=cnlogn`

But, `T(n)=2T(n/4)+T(n/2)+n`

Using the hipothesis we get:

`T(n)<=2(c(n/4)log(n/4))+c(n/2)log(n/2)+n=cnlogn + n(1-3c/2)`

So, taking `c>=2/3` would prove our thesis, because then `T(n)<=cnlogn`

Now we need to prove the base case:

We will take `n0=2` because if we take `n0=1`, the `logn` would be `0` and that wouldn't work with our thesis. So our base cases would be `n=2,3,4`. We need the following propositions to be true:

`T(2) <= 2clog2`

`T(3) <= 3clog3`

`T(4) <= 4clog4`

So, by taking `c=max{2/3, T(2)/2, T(3)/3log3, T(4)/8}` and `n0=2`, we would be finding constants `c` and `n0` such that for every natural `n>=n0`, `T(n)<=cnlogn`

The demonstration for `T(n) = W(nlogn)`  is analog.

So basically, in these cases where you can't use the Masther Theorem, you need to 'guess' the result and prove it by induction.

For more information on these kind of demonstrations, refer to 'Introduction to Algorithms'

Comment: Dear Orlando, thank you very very much, great explanation and thanks for your time and patience. Let me invite you to my blog to share knowledge: shareinfoblog.blogspot.com Hope to see your comments and posts there.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to define some limits on this, otherwise it won't ever end and you will stuck up with OverflowException.
Something like the n is integer and the minimal value is 0.

Could you please bring up more details on your question in this manner ?

Comment: n>=1 and it's natural number.

Answer (score 1):

This won't help you figure out how to do it necessarily, but apparently Wolfram Alpha can get the right answer. Perhaps you can look for documentation or have Mathematica show you the steps it takes in solving this:

[Wolfram Alpha: `T(n)=2*T(n/4)+T(n/2)+n`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T%28n%29%3D2%2aT%28n%2F4%29%2BT%28n%2F2%29%2Bn)

To put crude upper and lower bounds on the search space, you could have recognized your T(n) is bounded above by 3T(n/2) + n and below by 2T(n/4) + n... so O(n^(3/2)) and W(n), by the master theorem.

In general, solving recurrence relations hard problem.